# Can't seem to be able to grab non-string output from run

Tags: io, raku

> I can't think of other way to run a command line that outputs binary files, so I'll have to go with this.

Let's add a binary file to a git repository

```
mkdir test
cd test
git init .
wget https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/85/Camelia.svg/320px-Camelia.svg.png
git add 320px-Camelia.svg.png
git commit -am "Added Camelia"
```

Grab the commit hash that that outputs, we'll use it as `<grabbed hash>` below.

Now, run this:

```
say (run "git", "show", "<grabbed hash>:Camelia.svg.png", :out).out
```

This will return a `Malformed UTF-8` message. Fair enough, it's not binary. However, I have tried to capture that exception with `try` and there's no way. I've tried to separate the run from the `out`, I still get an exception that can't be captured. Any idea?

Comment: What is the `<grabbed hash>:` about ?

Comment: I get `IO::Pipe<(Path)>(opened)` ?  In any case, you generally call something like `.slurp` or `.lines`on whatever `.out` returns.  With `.slurp` you can indicate to import as `:bin` ?

Comment: I just got the same results as Liz. Using replit.com (`v2021.07`).

Comment: @ElizabethMattijsen it's whatever hash you obtain when you commit the image file.

Comment: @ElizabethMattijsen It breaks when calling `out`. I can't slurp it, binary or otherwise. Problem is, I can't catch the exception so that it's run with binary output. @raiph I doubt it works in repl.it. You need to actually have a binary file, as in the example provided.

Comment: @JJ I fixed errors in your instructions (eg missing `320px-` prefix for `commit add`) but I doubt they're so bad Liz and I have reproduced the same result for different reasons. I imagine [Camelia](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/85/Camelia.svg/320px-Camelia.svg.png) is as non-binary as Audrey, but she sure *looks* binary.

Comment: @JJ I followed your instructions. You can do so too; just start [a fresh Raku replit](https://replit.com/languages/raku) and use the shell (normally on the right). `nix` will prompt for installation of a `wget` package; I picked `wget.out`. At the end, `raku -e 'say (run "git", "show", "84226c9:320px-Camelia.svg.png", :out).out'` did not display `Malformed UTF-8` but `IO::Pipe<(Path)>(opened)`. This only took a couple minutes. Please consider using replit too to confirm you get the same result. At least we'll then know this problem is system or Rakudo version specific.

Comment: @raiph you are right. Hum.

Comment: @raiph I think it's maybe `git` version specific; but at any rate, it's difficult to find now what are those versions. And still, @jnthn answer has been accepted. I can do other edits if that's helpful, but other than adding it was Ubuntu 20.04 (no kernel version that I remember), there's not much I can do.

Comment: Well, I'm confused *now*. Feel free to edit the OP, you have privs for that.

Comment: I've figured it out. There's no bug. You forgot that one must specify `:bin` when using IO functions that assume strings by default, to read or write a binary file. That includes `.slurp`, and the `:out` option of `run`. The solutions were/are either Liz's suggestion (`.slurp(:bin)` for final output) or jnthn's (`:bin` with `:out` for the `run`). In summary, the answer is "add a `:bin`" when dealing with binary files.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Pass the `:bin` option to `run` in order to have it do binary I/O instead. Example using `curl`:

```
$ raku -e 'say (run "curl", "--no-progress-meter", "https://raku.org/camelia-logo.png", :out, :bin).out.slurp'
Buf[uint8]:0x<89 50 4E 47 0D 0A 1A 0A 00 00 00 0D 49 48 44 52 00 00 01 05 00 00 00 F3 08 06 00 00 00 8F 2A 03 21 00 00 00 01 73 52 47 42 00 AE CE 1C E9 00 00 00 09 70 48 59 73 00 00 0F 61 00 00 0F 61 01 A8 3F A7 69 00 00 00 07 74 49 4D 45 07 D9 07 11 03 07 3A 28 6B FA 81 00 00 00 1A 74 45 58 74 43 6F 6D 6D 65 6E ...>
```

Comment: But then, it would need to decode for the most common option, which is string, right?

Comment: Not sure I follow; if you use `run` without `:bin`, it's just doing the `decode` step for you. Since your data is binary, decoding it makes no sense?